# gmtl libraries VecBase.h and vec.h

Tags: opengl

I have been reading "Interactive Computer Graphics: A Top Down Approach" 6th Edition.
I was wondering, the writer uses a library "Angel.h" that I manage to download, but "g++" is still complaining about gmtl libraries "VecBase.h and vec.h". how can I download/link gmtl to g++ ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use [`gmtl`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ggt/files/Generic%20Math%20Template%20Library/0.6.1/).  [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) is way better.

If you *have* to use `gmtl`:  It's header-only so you should just be able to [point `g++` at it via `-I`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html).